# Video playback app for iOS 6 that's like iOS 7's Videos.app?

Tags: applications, video, ios

Is there an iOS 6-compatible app that's just like the iOS 7 Videos.app? I have tried VLC but I want an app that displays the contents of my video library as both text and thumbnails the way the the Videos.app does.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Ask Different! It's a little unclear what you're asking for here -- do you want something like the Videos.app but does more than the Video.app does?

Comment: No i want something just like the videos.app

Comment: Im looking for a tweak/app Thats just like videos app not ios 7 movie playback?

Comment: No sweat. I've tweaked the title and dropped some unnecessary verbiage in your question. Hopefully that helps net you the answer you seek!

Comment: @IanC. Do you know any app Thats just like the videos app?

Answer (score 1):

VLC for iPhone works from iOS 6.1?

If that's fine, heres the link:

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/vlc-for-ios/id650377962?mt=8

Movie Player works from iOS 5.1, here's the link:

https://itunes.apple.com/ae/app/movie-player-plays-any-video!/id406779775?mt=8

Comment: Yes but movie player doesnt show the whole text on the video

Comment: Sorry I dont know, but if you're desperate I can develop you one ;)

Comment: Whats develop? Sorry i dont know much about jailbreaking.

Comment: If you can create a app or tweak like this then yes please do that.

Comment: You can contact me for details :p

Comment: Where do i go to contact or should i just write it down here?

Comment: Isnt my profile visible to all? Email jp at weconnect dot ae

Comment: Yes it is i just tough u mean contacting you on this site sorry my bad. But do you do this for free? I mean making the app?